# How should I shim furring strips to bring them on plane with an adjacent wall?

Tags: drywall

We removed some old wood panels from the wall in one of our rooms with the plan to install drywall in its place. Behind the wall we found what looks like existing furring strips (approx. 1 inch thick x 2 wide) running horizontally across the studs. The challenge we have is that attaching 1/2 inch drywall directly to these furring strips would leave us about a 1/4 to 1/2 inch too shallow compared to the other adjoining walls in the room. It's an old house so depth can vary.

What is the appropriate way to handle this? Can we extend the existing furring strips with 0.5 inch lumber or is there an alternative approach?

Comment: This is a wall that continues into another room or area, and so you want the surface of the wall to all be in the same plane?

Comment: Hi Steve - yes that's right. The wood paneling was in a nook area off an another room (plaster walls in that room) so looking to have the new drywall level with those existing walls rather than a 1/2 inch step between them.

Comment: How are they attached?

Comment: The current set furring strips are nailed into the existing studs.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, just fur those walls out to where you want them.

I would use 1/2" plywood strips rather than regular lumber to avoid them splitting when being fastened or fastened to. Alternately, you could use 2 layers of drywall with the bottom one being 1/2" thick. Make sure to use longer fasteners for the drywall so you get it secured well to the underlying wood.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for the response.